# Check for applications using same port

Tags: windows, port

I am getting an error in hMailServer log that `some other application is using the ports 25 and 110 please make sure that they are disabled` How to find which application is using these port?

Comment: Please use appropriate tags when posting questions. It helps others to provide suitable answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
netstat -nao | findstr ":25\> :110\>"
```

- `\>` means the end of word

Comment: It's far from obvious from the question but as it's running hMailServer it must be a Windows machine.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've converted to Windows syntax.

Answer (score 1):

From a command prompt, type `netstat -anb`

This will show you all the ports open on your machine, along with the PID (process id) that has them open.

Look for port 25 and 110 and the PID.  Then open Task Manager and find the PID, and you'll find the process name that has them open.